# PHP site will not work

Tags: php

I have never used php before and are having some problems with running a test site we have been given.

Here is an image of the code and setup:

[image]

I have installed MAMP and it should work. I can create a site and use phpinfo() and the site opens and is showing the information. The problem is when I try to run the project (on the image over), then the site is just empty.

anyone have suggestions on what the problem can be?

If it's hard to read from the image here is the code in text -

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var datakilde = new EventSource('sse2.php');
        datakilde.onmessage = function(e){
            document.body.innerHTML += e.data + '<br>';
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

sse2.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

function sendMsg($id, $msg){
    echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

while(true){
    $serverTime = time();
    sendMsg($serverTime, 'server time: ' . date("h:i:s", $serverTime));
    sleep(1);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is likely to be that the browser does not display information, unless it is of significant size. A possible solution would be to pad the information your want to send with spaces. However, this is cumbersome. Instead, look into AJAX with PHP and MySQL -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp. Also, have a look at long polling -> http://www.php-tagebuch.de/long-polling-mit-jquery-und-php-tutorial/. 
Good luck!